# Run selenium in different environments

Tags: selenium

Issue running into I have one selenium code that need to be run in different environments. One by one .the code in environment(sit) type a keyword and generate list of  terms , another environment (prod) do the same thing but generate different list. I need to validate the first appearing term from the list in sit and prod  .the code is failing because what is in sit is different from prod .Is there generic way that can be used to run one code on both environments even if they generate different results .Can you please direct me ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve that.

1. One of the most appropriate (imho) ways to address *environment* independance is to use *environment* variables.
2. Another is to use property files holding different properties for different environments
3. Another one is to use your execution environment specific properties (like jvm properties in Java).

Options `1` and `3` are imho the most suitable for integrating your code into CI process.

Answer (score 0):

You can passed those values via config file and read and use it in your test code